# Use TableView or TableViewController when I have Custom TableViewCell and want to do MVC

Tags: ios, model-view-controller, uitableview, tableview

1. Condition: I have a custom TableViewCell and I do all things programmatically, no xibs.
2. if I want to do a MVC（split the view and the action）, To use a TableView or to use a Single TableViewController, which is better for the MVC design?
3. As far as I know TableView is just a UI view, and TableViewController can contain some logic. Do that mean, if I want a strict MVC design, I need to use TableView and another object-c file to handle the logic of the TableView, TableViewCell.

I have searched this on stackoverflow, google, and do not have a specific answer or a good understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UITableViewCell subclass can act as Model. It can contain views that you display in UIView.

Create a method inside UITableViewCell subclass that inits the data and inserts it in the subviews of current cell.

In "tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath" method you instantiate your CustomCell class.

UITableViewController is the same as you will create by yourself UIViewController and put UITableView in it. It was subclassed from UIViewController only for user's convenience. And sets delegate and datasource without need from your side to set them.

Comment: thnx for ur words. after reading ur answer, i think to custom a table view is the same to custom a tableviewcell. That is to say, If anyone wants to custom a table view, he needs to custom a tableviewcell and instantiate the tableviewcell in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: Sorry, but UITableViewCell is a view class, it inherits from UIView. And you do present views in it, for instance a label or an image. I also don't understand the assertion about UITableViewController that "It was subclassed from UIViewController only for user's convenience"? It is a full-blown view controller.

Comment: Agree with you about the first part, I'm gonna edit it. But about UIViewController I disagree. You can do the same things with UIViewController by using TableView's delegate, without UITableViewController.

Comment: My source: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/introduction-to-the-ios-uitableviewcontroller#disqus_thread

Answer (score 2):

I used to keep

1. custom "Model" object which contains username, city and image of the user, Suppose in a class "User.h" and "User.m"
2. custom "View" object which contains two UILabel to display name and city and UIImageView to display user picture, suppose named "CellUser"
3. custom "Controller" object which can contain datasource and datadelegate methods of UITableView, for instance "UserViewController", a subclass of "UIViewController".

Custom UITableView class can be created according to necessity for the project, suppose when you need same data to be displayed more than one page of the project.

Hope it helps you understanding!